# Inno Setup Compiler: How to install a service

Tags: inno-setup

After Inno instlls my app, I want Inno to install 2 services with the properties of the installation folder in the windows services list.

I have installed `wamp` and I want to add a new service for `apache` and `new service for`mysql`

`apacheServiceInstallParams = -n wampapachec -k install`

`mysqlServiceInstallParams = --install-manual wampmysqldc`

```
function InstallService(const FileName, ServiceName, 
  DisplayName: string; ServiceType, StartType: DWORD): Boolean;
var
  ManagerHandle: SC_HANDLE;
  ServiceHandle: SC_HANDLE;
begin
  Result := False;
  ManagerHandle := OpenSCManager('', '', SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);
  if ManagerHandle <> 0 then
  begin
    try
      ServiceHandle := CreateService(ManagerHandle, ServiceName, 
        DisplayName, SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS, ServiceType, StartType,
        SERVICE_ERROR_IGNORE, FileName, '', 0, '', '', '');
      if ServiceHandle <> 0 then
      begin
        Result := True;
        CloseServiceHandle(ServiceHandle);
      end
      else
        MsgBox(SysErrorMessage(DLLGetLastError), mbError, MB_OK);
    finally
      CloseServiceHandle(ManagerHandle);
    end;
  end
  else
    MsgBox(SysErrorMessage(DLLGetLastError), mbError, MB_OK);
end;

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then
  begin
    if InstallService(ExpandConstant('{app}\bin\aoache\apache2.2.22\bin\httpd.exe'),
      'wampapachecow',
      'MySQL', SERVICE_WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS, SERVICE_AUTO_START)
    then
      MsgBox('MySql Service installation succeeded!', mbInformation, MB_OK);
    if InstallService(ExpandConstant('{app}\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\bin\mysqld.exe'),
      'wampmysqldcow',
      'MySQL', SERVICE_WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS, SERVICE_AUTO_START)
    then
      MsgBox('MySql Service installation succeeded!', mbInformation, MB_OK);
  end;
end;
```

what i don't understand:

I have it like this:

```
InstallService(ExpandConstant('{app}\bin\aoache\apache2.2.22\bin\httpd.exe'),
      'wampapachecow',
      'MySQL', SERVICE_WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS, SERVICE_AUTO_START)
```

it should be like this?

```
InstallService(ExpandConstant('{app}\MySQL 5.5\bin\mysqld.exe'),
      ExpandConstant('--defaults-file="{app}\MySQL 5.5\my.ini"'),
      'MySQL', SERVICE_WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS, SERVICE_AUTO_START)
```

please explain the second parameter:

`'wampapachecow'` and `ExpandConstant('--defaults-file="{app}\MySQL 5.5\my.ini"')`

Comment: I need to review the original code. Or better, I'll post a series of Q&As for how to install, control and uninstall services. [I'm busy to do it now...]

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code to create a service and service will start automatically.

```
// create a system service with windows command “sc”
DosCmd := '/C '+'sc create "WCF" binPath= "'+ExpandConstant('{app}\WCF.exe' \
  type= share start= auto DisplayName= "WCF"'+' obj= '+UserName+' password= '+Passwd;
Exec(ExpandConstant('{cmd}'),DosCmd, '',  SW_HIDE,ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
```

and then, the WCF service will start automatically. For more help,run "sc /?" in windows.

Comment: Avoid using command line tools as much as you can. Always prefer native Windows API solutions. In this case you've shown no control over the situation when something goes wrong.

Comment: thank you,I am a green hand, I will  continue to learn INNO SETUP.